# loading txt files into matlab structure

Tags: matlab, structure

I have a txt file below as shown in the attached figure:

```
a 0.15
ne 1e25
density 200
pulse_num 2
```

Is has n rows, 2 data on each row. The first data is a sting that contains the field name, and the second data contains the value. The two data is separated by a space. How do I load this txt file into a matlab structure? Basically I want something like:

```
whatIwant = struct('a', 0.15, 'ne', 1e25, 'density', 200, 'pulse_num', 2)
```

I only know how to load it to a table (using `readtable`), and I can convert the table to a cell, then to a structure. Problem is that I don't know how to append a structure. I don't want to input the field names in my code, so if I change the field names (or don't know the field names) the final structure will have the appropriate field names.

Or are there other simple ways to load it directly?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using:

```
fid = fopen('info.txt');     %Opening the text file
C = textscan(fid, '%s%s');   %Reading data
fclose(fid);                 %Closing the text file
%Converting numeric data stored as strings in a cell to numeric data using cellfun
s=cell2struct(cellfun(@str2double,C{2},'un',0),C{1},1); %Converting into a structure array
```

Read the documentation of [**`fopen`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), [**`textscan`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/textscan.html), [**`fclose`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fclose.html), [**`cellfun`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) and [**`cell2struct`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2struct.html) for details.

Comment: It's fine in this case, but `str2double` would generally be safer than `str2num`.