# How to create an array of structures?

Tags: matlab, data-structures, structure

I made a structure using data in a text file using the codes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40538320/loading-txt-files-into-matlab-structure/40538587#40538587). Now suppose I have `n` such txt files and I want to load the information to `n` different structures, and I want to group those structures together. How can I do that?

For example, I have two such txt files:

```
# txt file #1
a 0.15
ne 1e25
density 200
pulse_num 2

# txt file #2
a 0.2
ne 2e25
density 100
pulse_num 3

data(1).a=0.15
data(2).a=0.2
data(1).ne=1e25
data(2).ne=2e25
```

and so on.

Since I don't know the content of each txt file, I need to use a for loop to load the data one-by-one. For can I achieve something similar to what I want?

Comment: Just make `a` and `ne` vectors, and append to them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to group your data in a structure, you can define an empty struct and then iteratively build up each struct in the struct array. Here is just a rough example:

```
for ii=1:numberOfFiles
    %process of reading in txt file ii, where you created an "a" and a "ne" variable
    %...
    data(ii) = struct('a', a, 'ne',ne );
end for
```